# Strange worm in fish tank

Tags: fish

I spotted this worm on the glass shortly after doing a water change.

I need aw help identifying it.

Tank is cold water, mix of Borneo sucker, guppies and two fire belly newts.

[image: worm]
[image: another worm]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to tell, so consider taking a better photo. If possible, a camera with a good macro setting may help to take a closer photo.

However, [does this](http://www.fishdeals.com/fish_diseases/planaria_white_worms/) look like what you've got?

> Planaria are often found in aquariums with uneaten food. The planaria
>   won't hurt the fish, but they are a symptom of too much gravel
>   containing too much uneaten food, and that is not good for fish. They
>   require a food source, which means there must be excess food wastes in
>   the tank to support them.

If they've been living on the food/waste in the gravel, it's possible you didn't notice them until you cleaned the tank. You remove the food, they move around more?

Comment: Tank is full of snails, I'm ok with that. It's the weird works that I noticed today that I'm wondering about

Comment: anything like this?
http://www.fishdeals.com/fish_diseases/planaria_white_worms/

Comment: Yep that's the one!

Answer (score 2):

I had them in my tanks. It is noting to be worry about. They usually appear when you do not change water regularly in your tank. When they appeared in my tank I have started to change 1/3 of water every 7 days and they disappeared.I have always prepare water for the tank do not use tap water